# Снятие скриншота при помощи listener

Tags: java, testng, appium

Доброго дня!
Хочу написать листенер, который будет делать скрин при ошибке.

Соответственно есть класс

```
public class Listener  implements ITestListener {

  public void onTestFailure(ITestResult result) {

  }
```

и в testng.xml прописан листенер:

Как мне написать метод onTestFailure

Comment: просто как предложение: не лучше ли сделать необходимые действия в теле обработки исключений?

Comment: Пример можно? Он подойдет для уже существующего проекта (там более 100 тестов)?

Comment: Рекомендую посмотреть в сторону [allure framework](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure2), [пример того как это может выглядеть](https://ci.qameta.io/job/allure2/job/master/Demo_Report/index.html#suites/1bbdddb8b139ac506f125d271028f72a/b82e71b0159ff0b3/?attachment=7a0e7a5560256877)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    import java.awt.Rectangle;
    import java.awt.Robot;
    import java.awt.Toolkit;
    import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
    import java.io.File;
    import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
public class Listener  implements ITestListener {

  public void onTestFailure(ITestResult result) {
            Robot robot = new Robot();
            BufferedImage screenShot = robot.createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()));
            ImageIO.write(screenShot, "JPG", new File(<yourPath>+".jpg"));

  }
```

Необходимо только указать путь + формат.